# how to graph $f(x) = x^x .$

Tags: calculus, functions

I am having problem plotting the function $f(x) = x^x$ because $0^0$ is undefined (or is it?) and can it have weird values on the negative values of the domain.

I tried plotting it on google graphs, desmos, and geogebra, and the graph had a value of 1 when $x=0$ and the domain was restricted only to a set of positive real numbers and zero as well.
so if i could get a bit help on it....

[image]

Comment: What's a domain of $0$?

Comment: You can use $1$ instead of $0^0$. For negative real $x$ you get complex values for $x^x$ with the exception of countable values.

Comment: The function $f(x)=x^x$ is usually defined at the origin to be $1$ so that it is continuous and differentiable in the domain $x\ge 0$.

Comment: @user90369 and @ Dr. MV,, You are trying to say that $ 0^0 $ is 1??

Comment: @Sarmad Rafique : No, but here it's without contradiction and therefore it works. Calculation with $x:=\frac{1}{n}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ : $\ln((\frac{1}{n})^\frac{1}{n})=\frac{-\ln n}{n}\to 0$ for $n\to\infty$ .

Answer (score 3):

The value at $0$ is indeed an undetermined form $0^0$. Anyway the limit

$$\lim_{x\to0}x^x=1,$$ calling for the continuation $f(0)=1$.

The case of the negatives depends on the convention. One convention states that the powers of the negatives are undefined. Another convention states that the rational powers of the negatives are defined by the equivalence

$$x^{p/q}=\sqrt[q]{x^p}$$ which is defined for odd $q$ (assuming $p/q$ irreducible).

With this convention, the plot in the negatives has a strange appearence, with

- no value for irrational $x$,
- $-|x|^x$ for $x$ rational with odd numerator and denominator,
- $|x|^x$ for $x$ rational with even numerator and odd denominator.

Even though it is impossible to draw the curve (as the domain is "dotted"), it looks like the pair of symetric curves

$$\pm|x|^x$$ when the points have finite size.

[image: enter preformatted text here]

Comment: How do account for the explanation behind the shape of the curve when $x>0$?

Comment: @RumpyPumpy: no idea what you are asking.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think you need to do some differentiation to justify the slope and minimum point of the curve, rather than just relying on graphical software.

Comment: @BeansonToast: the question was mainly about the handling of negative and zero $x$. I didn't discuss the variations at all, which is routine work.

Answer (score 1):

The function has real value only if $x>0$. You  can see it as:
$$
f(x)=x^x=\left( e^{\ln x}\right)^x=e^{x \ln x}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick note to add to Emilio's answer. Note that

$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+} x\ln x = \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\ln x}{1/x} = \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1/x}{-1/x^2} = -\lim_{x\to 0^+}x = 0
$$

So that

$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0^+}x^x = \lim_{x\to 0^+}e^{x\ln x} = e^0=  1
$$